# url_launcher not working in flutter when uploading to play store. Works in debug mode though?

Tags: flutter

I have released the app on play store, but the url_launcher is not working their. It works perfectly fine on debug mode.

Comment: did you run in release mode locally and check if it is working there?

Comment: Try running you app in release mode first and then check the logs in terminal hopefully you will find some errors/warning related to it. Then you can find the optimal solution accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is cause of the API level 30, you need to add new permissions to the adnroid.manifext.xml